# Download .xcdatamodeld file and create .momd programmatically

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm toying a lot with core data lately, and what bugs me is that you create a .xcdatamodeld to create your base structure, but then xcode convert it in a .momd file

My question is this : is it possible to do the conversion programmatically, instead of having it done by xcode?

Let's say for instance we wan't to be able to download a xcdatamodeld file from internet in an iOS app, and have it interpret it and create the underlying base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you download the entire `xcdatamodeld` bundle (it's a directory) and unpack it, you can use code from my [momcom](https://github.com/atomicbird/momcom) project to compile it into a `.momd`. You could then load that like any other data model. This project is still somewhat experimental, but it's performed well in testing so far. [**Update:** the project won't work on iOS as it is, because it uses `NSXMLDocument`. If you wanted to try this, you could use [`TouchXML`](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML), which is designed to be a drop-in replacement for `NSXMLDocument`. I don't know of any other options for compiling a Core Data model in your own app.]

The usual rules about having a data model and a persistent store match up apply. You couldn't just take the newly compiled model and use it with an existing store unless you handled model migration. Also, I have no idea what Apple's attitude would be regarding an app that downloaded new data model files-- it might be fine, or it might get you into some trouble with them.

Comment: An interesting approach. It's a shame that there is no built-in compiler though :'(

Answer (score 4):

You can create a momd file starting from an xcdatamodeld source using the **momc** script from Apple.

> An xcdatamodeld “source” directory is compiled into a momd deployment directory, and an xcdatamodel “source” file is compiled into a mom deployment file.

(As explained here **https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdUsingMOM.html**)

How to use the script:

1. Make a copy of the xcdatamodeld file you want to transform. It will be replaced.
2. Open the terminal and go to the Developer bin folder

   `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/`
3. Run the **momc** script on your xcdatamodeld file

   > Usage: momc source destination

   Example (it's important to put extensions):

   > **./momc input.xcdatamodeld  result.momd**

Comment: Interesting! But sadly, I don't think that momc is available from within an iPhone...

Answer (score 0):

No you can't download a xcdatamodeld file from internet and put it working. If you do so your programme will crash because of wrong data model. your data model needs to be in the main bundle and you have to select current data model. Core data maintain model version and some information  about your data model. Even if you change your model and do not migrate the model your programme will crash and you have to delete the application from your device/simulator.

However, you can download the .sqlite database but data model should be the same.

Comment: Not really. Although it's not a good approach, I have an app that downloads the model as well as sqlite data from the internet. Changing the model is works fine. However, this app was submitted long ago (in 2012, is still live).